# Read string from sign to sign from string

Tags: android, string

I'm trying to find a way to read some specified part from input string. I have a incoming input ( only integers ) where I have special signs for separate a data . It's looks like : *< data1 >,< data2 >,< data3 >*. 
My question is how to do a proper solution for reading it to separate variables?

Comment: Regex / String#Split depends on the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String[] separated = DataString.split(",");

separated[0]; // this will contain data1
separated[1]; // this will contain data2
```

**EDIT :-**

> I need to read data between " < " and " > " . so how should I do it ?

Well, After the inital split as show above you can go with substring with startindex of "<" and endindex of ">"

```
separated[0] = strData.substring((separated[0].indexOf("<") + 1), separated[0].indexOf(">"));
```

hope this helps...

Comment: ok but I need to read data between " < " and " > " . so how should I do it  ?

Answer (score 0):

String#split is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

StringTokenizer is the easiest solution!